# Validate field with @Enumerated annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I need to validate an entity with the @Valid annotation.
A field of my entity can take a set of numerical values and I thought to use the @Enumerated annotation.
It may take the values ​​5, 10, 15, 20 and 30.
Can I handle it with that annotation?
How?

Thanks!

UPDATE

I solved my issue in the following way:

I created an annotation @ValidateIntegerSet

```
@Documented  
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})  
@Constraint(validatedBy=IntegerSet.class)
public @interface ValidateIntegerSet {

int[] acceptedValues();

String message() default "Il valore inserito non è tra quelli ammissibili"; 

Class<?>[] groups() default { };

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { }; 
}
```

I created an class IntegerSet to perform the validation

```
public class IntegerSet implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateIntegerSet, Integer> {  

private List<Integer> valueList;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidateIntegerSet constraintAnnotation) {
    valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int val : constraintAnnotation.acceptedValues()) {
        valueList.add(Integer.valueOf(val));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if(!valueList.contains(value)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I have used the new annotation in the following way:

```
@ValidateIntegerSet(acceptedValues={5, 10, 15, 20, 30})
```

Comment: suggestion will be: write your own validator for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Enumerated

is for sure something that won't work. You need custom validator for that, as there is no build-in validator for that. You *could try* to use **@Pattern**

[Custom Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html)

Comment: The Enumerated and Pattern Annotations are the wrong way.
The best way is the creation of a custom validator.
Thanks for the tip!